# How to use Route53, or any other service, to redirect to a "backup" site when the main one is unreachable

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, redundancy

I have example.com managed by a DNS server that associates it to some IP address (ip1), owned by a first web server where the full site is hosted.

I also have a secondary webserver (with ip2) that hosts a "backup" site, with only the public pages (homepage, about, etc.) and with some other pages (signup, login etc.) that just show a "under maintanance" webpage. This is a very inexpensive and not very powerful machine, that I'll just use to see some static pages in case the real site is down...instead of a sad connection error / site not found error.

Now I'd like to find/configure a service that automatically redirects example.com to ip2 when the webserver that own ip1 goes down. I know I could manually change the DNS records so that example.com points to ip2, but I'd like to find something that is very fast and automatic (so that I don't need to wake up at night to do that).

Any idea, suggestion, guidance?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Write a script that tests the return code html of your primary site (hosted on secondary server). In case of failure or timed out, you can change the associated record with the [Route 53 API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeResourceRecordSets.html).

And do not forget to use a low TTL...

Comment: this might work...but it requires a custom script and a machine that's always running it. I'd prefer a ready-to-use service...I'm sure something must exist. Found yottaa so far, but haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Ok, in this case, I recommend https://www.cloudflare.com/. You will not even need your backup server.